# NSInternalInconsistencyException when saving second entity in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I went through a lot of questions here, but it is still unclear.

I have 5 tabs in my app (tab bar app) and each tab is responsible for pushing some detail into 1 table. So in effect one table for each tab.

I initialised `managedObjectContext` properly and was successful in saving the data in the entity. Now when I try to push data into the second table, I am getting this exception:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'OtherDetail'*

Is it necessary to push data into all the entities in one go?

```
(void)persistOtherDetail:segCtrlValue:genInfoId:type:labelValue{
NSLog(@"Persisting %@",type);

NSLog(@"seg control value %@", segCtrlValue);

OtherDetail *otherDetail = (OtherDetail *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"OtherDetail" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
otherDetail.enteredValue = segCtrlValue;

otherDetail.genInfoId = genInfoId;
otherDetail.checklistDesc = labelValue;
otherDetail.checklistName = type;

NSError *error;

if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Problem saving: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post the portion of code where you try to persist data to "OtherDetail?"

Comment: your method signature is hurting my eyes

Comment: @VinceBurn u are talking about the arguments? I needed a method to which I can pass these 4 params, as i need to call this again and again from different tabs.

Comment: yes, its not the number of params it's the fact they are all squeezed up and look like they are missing some parts `- (void)persistOtherDetail:(int)segCtrlValue genInfoId:(int)anId withChecklistType:(int)aType forLabelValue:(NSString *)theLabelTxt` maybe I'm a purist for those and got that one wrong, but I like the way it's done in the Apple's framework, each method is telling a story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing immediately jumps out at me in your code, but in my experience that error often occurs because the `managedObjectContext` instance is not valid, or because of a simple spelling error when referencing an entity or entity attribute.  For the first cause, you could set a check against the context (before creating the OtherDetail object), and instantiate it if nil:

```
if (managedObjectContext == nil) { managedObjectContext = [(MyAppDelegateName *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

Otherwise, I would go back and check for any spelling mistakes.  Most likely, though, you properly set up the `managedObjectContext` in the first tab view controller, but not in the other.

Comment: Voila, it eventually solves my problem. Thank u :) , I found this suggested fix in other questions as well, just could not figure out where to place this code. I know this sounds like a dumb new bie. Thanks anyws!!